# How to export data from DataGridView without using FileDialog?

Tags: c#, datagridview, export, export-to-excel

I have a button called Export Data. When I click on this button the data should store by default in a file "abc.xls".

I am able to store the data but When I try to store the values 2nd time I am getting COMException.

Can anyone suggest me on this?

I do not want to have a filedialog. Since I am using a default file and everytime I change I override the file. Thanks in advance.

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = 
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
 {
    for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
    {
      DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
    }
 }

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\abc.xls", 
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, 
               misValue, misValue, misValue,
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                 misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue); 
                // A COMException is thrown here

 xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
 xlApp.Quit();

 releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
 releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
 releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: Post exception and You "Export Data" method

Answer (score 0):

Saying .xls and COMException, I suspect you mean saving via Excel COM automation. Then you would set DisplayAlerts = false and use SaveAs method. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    var f = new Form {Text = "Excel SaveAs sample"};
    var b = new System.Windows.Forms.Button {Text="Save as xls", AutoSize = true};
    var dgv = new DataGridView {Top=60};

    var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
    new SqlDataAdapter(
      "select CustomerId, CompanyName, ContactName from Customers", 
      @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes")
      .Fill( tbl );

    dgv.DataSource = tbl;

    f.Controls.Add( b );
    f.Controls.Add( dgv );

    b.Click += (sender, args) => {
      var xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
      var wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
      var sheet = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

      for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
        ((Range)sheet.Cells[1,i+1]).Value = dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
          ((Range)sheet.Cells[i+2,j+1]).Value = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();         
        }
      }
      xl.DisplayAlerts = false;
      wb.SaveAs(@"d:\temp\abc.xls");
      xl.Quit();
      MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    };

    f.Show();
}
```